# how to pass values to html from flask using codecs library

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to send OTP via email with email body in HTML . I could able to attach the html page with python code but i am unable to pass the generated OTP from python code to HTML body .

The python code is show below

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()  
msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = emailId
msg['Subject'] = "Check  OTP"
otp=4567
f=codecs.open("otp.html", 'r')
s1=f.read().format(otp=2354)   
part2 = MIMEText(s1, 'html')
msg.attach(part2)
```

i want to display the otp(4567) in the email's HTML body .

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your html code

```
<p>otp is: <!-->otp<--></p>
```

In your python file:

```
from envelopes import Envelope
otp = 1234
html = ''
filename = 'yourhtml.html'
fp = file.read(filename,'r')
for line in fp:
    if "<p>otp is: <!-->otp<--></p>" in line:
        line = line.replace("<!-->otp<-->",str(otp))
    html+=line
envelope = Envelope(from_addr="someaddress", to_addr="someother", subject=u"check the html",text_body=u'Plain text version',html_body=html))
envelope.send('smtp.gmail.com', login='login@gmail.com', password='********', tls=True)
```